# Dagger 2 cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method with a qualified dependency

Tags: android, dagger-2

I tried to inject my adapter in two different fragments, using dagger 2. But catch error

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @javax.inject.Named("pharmacy") MedicinesAdapter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Here is my AdapterModule

```
@Module
class AdapterModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideMedicinesAdapter(clickListener: MedicinesAdapter.ClickListener): MedicinesAdapter =
        MedicinesAdapter(clickListener = clickListener)

    @Provides
    @Named("pharmacy")
    fun provideClickListenerForPharmacy(fragment: PharmacyFragment): MedicinesAdapter.ClickListener =
        fragment

    @Provides
    @Named("medicines")
    fun provideClickListenerForMedicines(fragment: MedicinesFragment): MedicinesAdapter.ClickListener =
        fragment
}
```

inject in fragment

```
 @field:[Inject Named("medicines")]
 lateinit var medicinesAdapter: MedicinesAdapter
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `AdapterModule` you provide `MedicinesAdapter` without any `@Named` parameters. However, in a fragment, you want to get `MedicinesAdapter` field with `@Named("medicines")`. Probably you forgot to specify `@Named` for your adapter provider method.

```
@Provides
@Named("medicines")
fun provideMedicinesAdapter(clickListener: MedicinesAdapter.ClickListener): MedicinesAdapter = 
    MedicinesAdapter(clickListener = clickListener)
```